# twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on any:80: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: macos, tcp, twisted

I am currently working on a project to create a TCP server on mac os mountain lion. I wrote a script called: Server.py

Within this python script, I used twisted to listen upon port 80 as shown below:

```
reactor.listenTCP(80, factory)
reactor.run()
```

How ever I am getting errors as such:

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 436, in listenTCP
    p.startListening()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 641, in startListening
    raise CannotListenError, (self.interface, self.port, le)
twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on any:80: [Errno 13] Permission denied.
```

I am thinking is it because the tcp.py script has the wrong permission for admin user? or is there a way to set permission on the port < 1024? (To change the permission, how would it affects the security of such a server?)

Any better solutions is apprieciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this issue using command  sudo + starting your server.

Comment: Help for me. But can you please explain why we need "sudo" at starting ?

Comment: In OS, by default there are some actions only permitted by administrators. Putting "sudo" before command then provide user credentials basically means you are authorizing such an action. Starting a server means allowing access to internet which may impose security threat, so it make sense that only admin of this machine are allowed to do it.

Comment: Thanks for improve my knowledge.

Answer (score 20):

Just go to the terminal and type sudo python server.py. Now it will ask password, type your password. Your problem will be solved. Happy coding

Comment: Help for me. But can you please explain why we need "sudo" at starting ?

Comment: Ports below 1024 needs to be root to be opened.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're on the right track.  By convention, only a super-user (or, in some newer systems, a normal user which has been granted certain special powers) is allowed to bind to ports below 1024.

The `authbind` tool is a handy way to grant this privilege to non-super-users.  There appears to be an OS X port, https://github.com/Castaglia/MacOSX-authbind (though I've only ever used authbind on Linux, myself).

Another approach is to have launchd bind the port for you and hand it off to your Twisted program.  This approach is more typical of what you might find people doing on OS X, and is accomplished using (the fairly recently introduced) `IReactorSocket.adoptStreamPort` API.  See the launchd documentation for details about how to configure this and how your Twisted program will learn where the socket it is to adopt.

Comment: twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on any:80: [Errno 48] Address already in use.

Have you ever experienced such an error. For most of posts on the forum, [Errno 98] has been complained a lot, but not 48. I did use "lsof -i :80" to check running processes binding to this port 80, then killed all of them including the web browser using "sudo kill PID". However, the problem remains. I am so confused now.

Comment: It's possible for a port to be in use even if no program is currently listening on it.  For up to two minutes after the program which was listening on it has exited (or otherwise closed the listening socket), TCP connections may remain in the TIME_WAIT state.  These prevent a new socket from listening on the port.  However, Twisted uses the SO_REUSEADDR feature of the BSD socket API to avoid this issue.

Comment: So, while you may sometimes see a "Address already in use" error even after no program is listening on a port anymore, that is probably not what is happening here.  It is more likely that some program really is still using the port.  It is highly unlikely that a web browser would ever be listening on port 80, so you may be misinterpreting the output of your tools.  Check again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your tcp46 is using your 80.
TURN OFF YOUR APACHE,EVERYTHING WILL BE FINE.

sudo apachectl stop